# CSS: Setting width/height as Percentage minus pixels to a table header column

Tags: css, width, pixel, calc, tablecell

Why in the following example do the columns of the header of the table not take the widths defined in the CSS?

I think in Table 1, the browser can not calculate a percentage value and a fixed one.

```css
/************* commun css***********************/
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   table-layout:fixed;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

tr{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/************* css table 1***********************/

.table1 .col1 {
  width: calc(35% - 10px);
}

.table1 .col2 {
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
}

.table1 .col3 {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.table1 .col4 {
  width: 30px;
}

/************* css table 2***********************/
.table2 .col1 {
  width: calc(30%);
}

.table2 .col2 {
  width: calc(20%);
}

.table2 .col3 {
  width: calc(50%);
}
```

```html
<p>
Table 1 : invalid render (Chrome browser)
</p>
<table class="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">Col 1</th>
      <th class="col2">Col 2</th>
      <th class="col3">Col 3</th>
      <th class="col4">Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
Table 2 : valid render (Chrome browser)
</p>

<table class="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">Col 1</th>
      <th class="col2">Col 2</th>
      <th class="col3">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any advice in this situation?

Thank you in advance

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/3wq65hb4/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem with calc() width for tables. But it works for divs. What about making it on divs instead of tables?

Let's look at example for your purposes:
https://jsfiddle.net/3wq65hb4/39/

You can find there:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

It's for equal height for columns. Also you can find there:

```
margin-left: -1px;
```

It's solution for borders - to avoid double borders like:

[image: Double column width]

Also remember that max-width for your column: 30px means that it always will be 30px even if your content will be wider:

[image: Wider column]

But maybe it's what you want to achieve.

Let me know if that solution is ok for you. And good luck with other htmls :)